# Database design: storing many large reports for frequent historical analysis

Tags: database, database-design, logging

I'm a long time programmer who has little experience with DBMSs or designing databases.

I know there are similar posts regarding this, but am feeling quite discombobulated tonight.

I'm working on a project which will require that I store large reports, multiple times per day, and have not dealt with storage or tables of this magnitude. Allow me to frame my problem in a generic way:

The process:

- A script collects roughly 300 rows of information, set A, 2-3 times per day.
  The structure of these rows never change. The rows contain two columns, both integers.
- The script also collects roughly 100 rows of information, set B, at the same time. The
  structure of these rows does not change either. The rows contain eight columns, all strings.

I need to store all of this data. Set A will be used frequently, and daily for analytics. Set B will be used frequently on the day that it is collected and then sparingly in the future for historical analytics. I could theoretically store each row with a timestamp for later query.

If stored linearly, both sets of data in their own table, using a DBMS, the data will reach ~300k rows per year. Having little experience with DBMSs, this sounds high for two tables to manage.

I feel as though throwing this information into a database with each pass of the script will lead to slow read times and general responsiveness. For example, generating an Access database and tossing this information into two tables seems like too easy of a solution.

**I suppose my question is: how many rows is too many rows for a table in terms of performance? I know that it would be in very poor taste to create tables for each day or month.**

Of course this only melts into my next, but similar, issue, audit logs...

Comment: These days, ~300k rows [isn't big for a spreadsheet](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005199291), let alone a database.

Comment: I have a table that stores 8 fields (date, 5 strings an integer and a double) and it grows by about 12 million rows/year. This is using `DB2 for i` - we have several years worth of data in there and have no problems querying the table. It's read frequently (many times a day) but only written to once per day. I can't imagine you having any problems as long as you're using any modern DBMS (DB2, MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostGREsql) that is properly indexed.

Answer (score 1):

300 rows about 50 times a day for 6 months is not a big blocker for any DB. Which DB are you gonna use? Most will handle this load very easily. There are a couple of techniques for handling data fragmentation if the data rows exceed more than a few 100 millions per table. But with effective indexing and cleaning you can achieve the performance you desire. I myself deal with heavy data tables with more than 200 million rows every week. 
Make sure you have indexes in place as per the queries you would issue to fetch that data. Whats ever you have in the where clause should have an appropriate index in db for it.

If you row counts per table exceed many millions you should look at partitioning of tables DBs store data in filesystems as files actually so partitioning would help in making smaller groups of data files based on some predicates e.g: date or some unique column type. You would see it as a single table but on the file system the DB would store the data in different file groups.
Then you can also try table sharding. Which actually is what you mentioned....different tables based on some predicate like date.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are over thinking this.  300k rows is not significant.  Just about any relational database or NoSQL database will not have any problems.

Your design sounds fine, however, I highly advise that you utilize the facility of the database to add a primary key for each row, using whatever facility is available to you.  Typically this involves using AUTO_INCREMENT or a Sequence, depending on the database.  If you used a nosql like Mongo, it will add an id for you.  Relational theory depends on having a primary key, and it's often helpful to have one for diagnostics.

So your basic design would be:

> Table A tableA_id | A | B | CreatedOn
>
> Table B tableB_id | columns… | CreatedOn

The CreatedOn will facilitate date range queries that limit data for summarization purposes and allow you to GROUP BY on date boundaries (Days, Weeks, Months, Years).

Make sure you have an index on CreatedOn, if you will be doing this type of grouping.

Also, use the smallest data types you can for any of the columns.  For example, if the range of the integers falls below a particular limit, or is non-negative, you can usually choose a datatype that will reduce the amount of storage required.